# Is there a way to provide content-type to python sharepoint add_item method?

Tags: python, sharepoint, python-requests, office365, office365-rest-client

My objective is to read a csv file using pandas and add records to sharepoint list (Mahesh_Demo) in truncate-load fashion.

My initial Sample code worked
Working/Sample Code

```py
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.runtime.client_request import ClientRequest
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('rt_PP_digital_door_Access.csv',dtype=str)
df = df.iloc[:100,:]

app_settings = {
     'url': 'https://host/sites/site_name/',
     'client_id': 'client-id',
     'client_secret': 'client_secret'
}

context_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=app_settings['url'])
context_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id=app_settings['client_id'],
client_secret=app_settings['client_secret'])
ctx = ClientContext(app_settings['url'], context_auth)
sp_list = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title("Mahesh_Demo")

# Truncate - Working
items = sp_list.items.get().top(1000000).execute_query()
for item in items:  # type: ListItem
    item.delete_object()
ctx.execute_batch()

# add records from csv to sharepoint list
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    sp_list.add_item({
        'Title': str(df.loc[i,"Title"]),
        'Name': str(df.loc[i,"Name"]),
        "Surname": str(df.loc[i,"Surname"])
    })
ctx.execute_query()
```

Actual code (Not working)

```py
from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.runtime.client_request import ClientRequest
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('rt_PP_digital_door_Access.csv',dtype=str)
df = df.iloc[:100,:]

app_settings = {
     'url': 'https://host/sites/site_name/',
     'client_id': 'client-id',
     'client_secret': 'client_secret'
}

context_auth = AuthenticationContext(url=app_settings['url'])
context_auth.acquire_token_for_app(client_id=app_settings['client_id'],
client_secret=app_settings['client_secret'])
ctx = ClientContext(app_settings['url'], context_auth)
sp_list = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title("Mahesh_Demo")

# Truncate - Working
items = sp_list.items.get().top(1000000).execute_query()
for item in items:  # type: ListItem
    item.delete_object()
ctx.execute_batch()

# add records from csv to sharepoint list
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    sp_list.add_item({
        'Title':str(i),
        'CATEGORY': str(df.loc[i,"CATEGORY"]),
        'APPLICATION_TYPE': str(df.loc[i,"APPLICATION_TYPE"]),
        'GXP_OR_NON_GXP': str(df.loc[i,"GXP_OR_NON_GXP"]),
        'USER_ID': str(df.loc[i,"USER_ID"]),
        'USER_NAME': str(df.loc[i,"USER_NAME"]),
        'OBJECT_NAME': str(df.loc[i,"OBJECT_NAME"]),
        'SQL_DATABASE': str(df.loc[i,"SQL_DATABASE"]),
        'WORKBOOK_LINK': str(df.loc[i,"WORKBOOK_LINK"])
    })
ctx.execute_query()
```

Error I'm getting

```py
ClientRequestException: ('-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException',
"The property 'CATEGORY' does not exist on type 'SP.Data.Mahesh_x005f_DemoListItem'. Make sure to only use property names that are defined by the type.",
"400 Client Error: Bad Request for url: https://mytakeda.sharepoint.com/sites/INSIGHTSANDANALYTICSDIGITALDOOR/_api/Web/lists/GetByTitle('Mahesh_Demo')/items")
```

I found the below solution on web which is on REST API. But I don't know how to add the Content-Type header to the add_item method.

```
Solution - Ensure that the Content-Type request header value is application/json;odata=verbose and not application/json.
```

[Solution](https://code2care.org/sharepoint/how-to-create-sharepoint-online-list-item-using-rest-api#:%7E:text=%E2%9A%A1%EF%B8%8F%20Create%20SharePoint%20list%20item%20from%20Postman%201,Send%20button%20to%20submit%20the%20request.%20More%20items)

Please let me know how to resolve this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My best guess is that the category field has had a name change since you built the list. By memory, the REST API always uses the original name. This might help you check if it's the same: https://plumsail.com/docs/help-desk-o365/v1.x/How%20To/Find%20the%20internal%20name%20of%20SharePoint%20column.html